# Is the theory of the complex field along with the real numbers $2^{\aleph_0}$-categorical?

Tags: model-theory

I know that the theory of the complex field $(\mathbb{C};+,-,*,0,1)$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$-categorical, while the theory of the real field $(\mathbb{R};+,-,*,0,1)$ is not. However, consider the structure $(\mathbb{C};+,-,*,0,1,R)$, where $R$ is a unary predicate that picks out the real numbers. Is the complete theory of that structure $2^{\aleph_0}$-categorical?

Comment: I'm about to go to bed, but I think this works? Take two nonisomorphic real closed fields (say $R$ and $R'$) of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. Then we can build two algebraically closed fields $C$ and $C'$ by adjoining a square root of $-1$ to each. Then $C$ and $C'$ are both continuum sized models of the complex field, but the predicates picking out the reals will (probably) give $R$ and $R'$, which are _not_ isomorphic, so there can be no isomorphism between the structures $(C,\ldots, R)$ and $(C',\ldots, R')$

Comment: High level reason why this cannot be true: clearly the proposed structure is unstable, there is a clear linear order in the reals. Anything that is uncountably categorical (in a countable signature) is in particular stable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing everyone should know about [categoricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_theory) for first-order theories is that it is an extremely rare phenomenon, and for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ (greater than or equal to the cardinality of the language), we have clear and restrictive criteria for when a theory $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical.
Let's assume the language is countable and $T$ is complete. Then:

- The [Ryll-Nardzewski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-categorical_theory) says (in one formulation) that $T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical if and only if there are only finitely many complete types over any finite set in a model of $T$.
- The Baldwin-Lachlan proof of Morley's categoricity theorem gives that $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for *some* uncountable $\kappa$ if and only if $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for *every* uncountable $\kappa$ if and only if $T$ is $\aleph_0$-stable with no Vaughtian pairs. We say $T$ is uncountably categorical in this case.

The condition of $\aleph_0$-stability means that there are only countably many complete types over any countable set in a model of $T$. It implies that $T$ is a [stable theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_theory). In particular, no theory which defines a order on some infinite subset of a model can be uncountably categorical.

---

Let $T$ be the complete theory of $(\mathbb{C};+,*,0,1,R)$, where $R$ picks out the real numbers. This theory defines the linear order on $R$, by $x\leq y$ iff $\exists z\, (R(z)\land z^2 = y-x)$. As Mark Kamsma notes in the comments, this immediately implies that $T$ is unstable, so it is not uncountably categorical.

We can also see that there are uncountably many complete types over $\mathbb{Q}$: for each irrational real number $r$, the complete type $\mathrm{tp}(r/\mathbb{Q})$ includes the information of which cut in $\mathbb{Q}$ contains $r$, so distinct real numbers have distinct complete types over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus $T$ is not $\aleph_0$-stable and not uncountably categorical.

In fact, $T$ is as far from being $2^{\aleph_0}$-categorical as possible: it has the maximal number of non-isomorphic models of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$: $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. This actually follows from general (un)stability theory - it's a theorem of Shelah that for every uncountable cardinal $\kappa$, every countable unstable theory has $2^{\kappa}$-many models of cardinality $\kappa$ up to isomorphism.

But to see this a bit more concretely, let's note that a model of $T$ is an algebraically closed field $C$ in which $R$ names a real closed subfield such that $R[i] = C$. In [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427857/isomorphism-classes-of-real-closed-subfields-of-bbb-c/4428432#4428432), I sketched how to construct $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many real closed fields of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ up to isomorphism. If $\mathcal{R}$ is one of these real-closed fields, then $(\mathcal{R}[i];+,*,0,1,\mathcal{R})$ is a model of $T$, and any isomorphism between two such models of $T$ induces an isomorphism between their distinguished real closed subfields. So this construction produces $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many non-isomorphic models of $T$.